# How to resolve angular datepicker format before and after post?

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-material

Using Angular Material Datepicker, when I submit the form I got:

> 2016-02-15T02:00:00.000Z

And when I tried format at PHP like:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post['date']))
```

I got:

> 2016-02-14

And when the date goes back to angular:

```
success: function(data) { $scope.date = new Date(data.date); }
```

I got:

> 2016-02-13

So, what am I doing so wrong

[UPDATE]

I put `date_default_timezone_set($timezone);` at my index.php

So before that I was doing:

`$str = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 day', strtotime($post['date'])));
$workaround = new Date($str);`

And now I changed to **+1 day**

I guess that the php timezone have resolved one of the issues.

Comment: You're likely running into a issue with timezones. Check the timezone of your php server and your local client

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to you timezone change. Since date from datepicker looks like `2016-02-15T02:00:00.000Z` which means , it is a datetime specific to UTC and when you send it to server, it converts it using your timezone causing previous date. 
You can send this date to server after removing decimal part like

> 2016-02-15T02:00:00